# Parallel for each inconsistent results

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I made sure I have concurrent collection inside parallel loop.I am expecting 35 unique file  paths at the end of the loop. I see inconsistent results with repeating file paths. What am I missing here?

```
ConcurrentBag<string> generatedPdfFilePaths = new 
    ConcurrentBag<string>();                   
string generatedPdfPath = string.Empty;   
Parallel.ForEach(docxPaths, (docxpath) =>                    
{
    generatedPdfPath = docxpath.Replace(".docx", ".pdf");
    if (ConvertDocxToPdf(docxpath, generatedPdfPath))
    { 
        generatedPdfFilePaths.Add(generatedPdfPath); 
    }                    
});

// do stuff with generatedPdfFilePaths collection here
public bool ConvertDocxToPdf(string docxFilePath, string pdfFilePath)
{               
    try
    {
        Aspose.Words.Document docx = new
            Aspose.Words.Document(docxFilePath);
        docx.FontSettings = fontsetting;
        docx.Save(pdfFilePath);                   
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //do stuff
    }                
}
```

Comment: Move `string generatedPdfPath = string.Empty;` inside `Parallel.ForEach` loop body. Now you are modifying it from multiple threads without any reason.

Comment: what is inconsistent about results ?

Comment: @InBetween Apologies - I ran the code through an online beautifier, didn't like the results, so reformatted it in Linqpad - I must have had the beautified version on my clipboard when I pasted it in Linqpad - mea culpa!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`generatedPdfPath`variable must be inside parallel loop. Otherwise it is accessable by all threads (parallel loops). Inside loops, every threads modify it and when thread tries to use it, 'probably' `generatedPdfPath` value is changed by another threads. This situation leads race condition. Hence, every each execution gives different result.

If you move this line `string generatedPdfPath = string.Empty;` into loop, problem must be solved.

```
ConcurrentBag<string> generatedPdfFilePaths = new ConcurrentBag<string>();                   

Parallel.ForEach(docxPaths, (docxpath) =>                    
{
    string generatedPdfPath = string.Empty;   
    generatedPdfPath = docxpath.Replace(".docx", ".pdf");
    if (ConvertDocxToPdf(docxpath, generatedPdfPath))
    { 
        generatedPdfFilePaths.Add(generatedPdfPath); 
    }                    
});
```